# QQ plot: More than two data

Tags: r, plot

I wanted to graph a QQ plot similar to this picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmyCu.png]

I managed to get a QQ plot using two samples, but I do not know how to add a third one to the plot.
Here is my result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VkgA.png]

Here is the code I used:

```
qqplot(table$Bedouin, table$Tunisia, xlim = c(-0.25,0.25), ylim = c(-025,0.25))
```

In my table data frame I have other populations I would like to add. But I can't.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I suppose you're looking for a scatterplot of sorted values since all variables are stored in the same data frame.

An example dataset:

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20), B = rnorm(20), C = rnorm(20))
```

This is a way to create the plot with basic R functions:

```
# create a QQ-plot of B as a function of A
qqplot(dat$A, dat$B, xlim = range(dat), ylim = range(dat), 
       xlab = "A", ylab = "B/C")
# create a diagonal line
abline(a = 0, b = 1)
# add the points of C
points(sort(dat$A), sort(dat$C), col = "red")
# create a legend
legend("bottomright", legend = c("B", "C"), pch = 1, col = c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

Comment: Any Idea how to do the same in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can add the line

```
par(new=TRUE)
```

Then use the qqplot() again to over-plot the first plot as follows:

```
set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(A = rnorm(20), B = rnorm(20), C = rnorm(20))

# create a QQ-plot of B as a function of A
qqplot(dat$A, dat$B, 
       xlim = range(dat), ylim = range(dat), 
       xlab = "Distribution A", ylab = "Other distributions")

# set overplotting
par(new=TRUE)

# create a QQ-plot of B as a function of C
qqplot(dat$A, dat$C, 
       xlim = range(dat), ylim = range(dat), 
       xlab = "Distribution A", 
       ylab = "Other distributions",
       col = "red")

# create a diagonal line
abline(a = 0, b = 1)

# create a legend
legend("bottomright", legend = c("B", "C"), pch = 1, col = c("black", "red"))
```