# Multiple qqplots on one gragh and single abline ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Borrowing from the example [QQ plot: More than two data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299374/qq-plot-more-than-two-data), how can one possibly implement it in `ggplot2`? I need `one abline` only.

**Sample data:**

```
set.seed(10)
   dat <- data.frame(Observed = rnorm(20), sim1= rnorm(20), sim2 = rnorm(20),sim3 = rnorm(20),sim4 = rnorm(20),sim5 = rnorm(20),sim6 = rnorm(20))
```

`sim1...sim6` should have different colors.

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Straightforward in `ggplot2` with `stat_qq` and reshaping your data from wide to long.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(Observed = rnorm(20), sim1= rnorm(20), sim2 = rnorm(20),sim3 = rnorm(20),sim4 = rnorm(20),sim5 = rnorm(20),sim6 = rnorm(20))

plot <- dat %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -Observed) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sample = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_abline() +
  stat_qq() 

# All in one
plot
```

[image]

It might be beneficial if you look at making facets or small multiples along your comparison variable.

```r
# Facets!
plot +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

If you're looking to provide your own observed, then rather than being fancy, let `qqplot` do the heavy lifting but set `plot.it = FALSE` and it will return you a list of x/y coords for the qq plot.  A little iteration with `purrr::map_dfr`, and you can do:

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
dat <- data.frame(Observed = rnorm(20), sim1 = rnorm(20), sim2 = rnorm(20),sim3 = rnorm(20),sim4 = rnorm(20),sim5 = rnorm(20),sim6 = rnorm(20))

plot_data <- map_dfr(names(dat)[-1], ~as_tibble(qqplot(dat[[.x]], dat$Observed, plot.it = FALSE)) %>% 
                   mutate(id = .x))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x, y, color = id)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline() +
  facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Jake Kaupp

Comment: `stat_qq` and `geom_qq` seem to seem to be designed to compare one or more vectors `e.g. sim1-6 vector` to a theoretical distribution, I couldn't see how to use it to compare two different vectors, `e.g each of sim1 to sim6 compared against Observed?` How can I do exactly what I specified in the link under my question but in `ggplot2`? Thank you.

Comment: This is where you would conduct your comparison outside of ggplot, then just use `geom_point` to plot your expected vs observed.

Comment: I guess an example with the sample data will shed more light on the problem better?

Comment: Updated the answer to address providing your own observed values.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Many thanks for the nice solution.