# Quantile-Quantile plot: compare multiple modelled variables vs one oberved variable ggplot2 R

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Sample data**

```
set.seed(10)
   dat <- data.frame(Observed = rnorm(20), 
                    sim1= rnorm(20), sim2 = rnorm(20),
                    sim3 = rnorm(20),sim4 = rnorm(20),
                    sim5 = rnorm(20),sim6 = rnorm(20)
                   )
```

`stat_qq` and `geom_qq` seem be designed to compare one or more vectors e.g. sim1-6 vectors to a theoretical distribution. I couldn't see how to use it to compare multiple different vectors, e.g each of `sim1` to `sim6` compared against `Observed`?

However, I have the output of a model (`sim1-sim6`) and would like to check if the modelled output compares with the the `Observed`.

How can I accomplish this in `ggplot2`? The `y-axis` is `sim1-sim6` and `x-axis` is `Observed`.

Remember: I am comparing each of `sim` to `Observed`.

All suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT:SOLUTION IN BASE R**

```
set.seed(10)
   dat1 <- data.frame(Observed = rnorm(20), sim1= rnorm(20), sim2 = rnorm(20),sim3 = rnorm(20),sim4 = rnorm(20),sim5 = rnorm(20),sim6 = rnorm(20))
   #
   # create a QQ-plot of Sims as a function of Observed
   qqplot(dat1$Observed, dat$sim1, xlim = range(dat1), ylim = range(dat1), 
          xlab = "Observed", ylab = "Sims....")
   # create a diagonal line
   abline(a = 0, b = 1)
   # add the points of sims
   points(sort(dat1$Observed), sort(dat1$sim2), col = "red")
   points(sort(dat1$Observed), sort(dat1$sim3), col = "blue")
   points(sort(dat1$Observed), sort(dat1$sim4), col = "green")
   points(sort(dat1$Observed), sort(dat1$sim5), col = "magenta")
   points(sort(dat1$Observed), sort(dat1$sim6), col = "purple")
```

[image]

**My question:**

How can one possibly accomplish the same task in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
data = melt(dat, id.vars = "Observed")
ggplot(data) +geom_qq(aes(sample=value)) + 
  geom_qq_line(aes(sample=Observed)) +
  facet_wrap(~variable)
```

[image]

**Update**

```
    data = melt(dat, id.vars = "Observed")
ggplot(data) +geom_qq(aes(sample=value, color = variable)) + 
  geom_qq_line(aes(sample=Observed))
```

[image]

Comment: This looks cool. However, what I really want to implement within `ggplot2` is the answer provided here `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20299374/qq-plot-more-than-two-data` in base R. I need just 1 graphwith 6 dotted lines. Put the the plots above in one graph, the 1:1 line represents the observed.

Comment: This answer is essentially there. To get in one plot instead of facets, just change the penultimate line to `geom_qq_line(aes(sample=Observed, color = variable))` and drop the last line.